# and hide in kal calendar gridview with a button

Tags: calendar, hide, kal

I have an application in which I want only show Kal calendar library, or when you press a button to display the calendar and if you press it again to be hidden, tapku style library. I do not work directly with that library and not how to admit you got right through a JSON data.